# Actionscript Timer doesn't stop after number of loops

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, timer

Pls help! I can't figure out why my Timer doesn't stop after number of loops. I declared a variable "roundCount" at the beginning. The Timer should have stopped when it's value is zero, right? But it keeps on decrementing the value of "roundCount"  3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,etc.

```
var roundLength:uint = 1000;
var roundCount:uint = 0;

con_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, conPoint);

function conPoint(m:MouseEvent)
{
    if (cB.height == 60)
    {
        conductSigns.conductMasker.y = 27;
        roundCount = 10;
        penaltyTimer.start();
    }
}

var penaltyTimer:Timer = new Timer(roundLength,roundCount);
penaltyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countDown);

function countDown(t:TimerEvent):void
{
    timeOut_txt.text = String(roundCount - penaltyTimer.currentCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this code roundCount is 0 so you start timer with repeatCount 0 wich is mean - repeat forever. [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#Timer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#Timer%28%29)
Also roundCount does not decrement. You substract from it  penaltyTimer.currentCount

To make the timer to execute in your case 3 times you must
sure that when create the timer roundCount is 3. Changing the value after creating the timer object will not reflect to the timer.

Comment: AzzyElvul - my timer does not start at zero, it starts at 10, because I changed the roundCount variable value in the conPoint function. But even if it starts at 10, it doesn't stop at zero, but goes on and on.

Comment: No! Your timer start from 0. You create it here: var penaltyTimer:Timer = new Timer(roundLength,roundCount); at this time roundCount is 0. In conPoint you set roundCount = 10; but this not reflect to penaltyTimer - it's already created. In countDown you just substract from roundCount - penaltyTimer.currentCount. To see how many times your timer will repeat see .repeatCount property ( penaltyTimer.repeatCount ) check this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#repeatCount so if you won to repeat 10 times set var roundCount:uint = 10;